# Different program behaviour in Windows XP and Windows 7

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, gdi

This code draws two vertical stripes from top to bottom of the window in two threads (corresponding function for each thread is `thread_func`). The first thread draws a part of the left stripe, then the second draws a part of the right one, then the first again and so on. A semaphore and a critical section are used to ensure this order.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdint>

HDC hDC; 
HDC  hDCMem;
HBITMAP hbitmap;
HWND  hwnd; 
int ScreenMaxX;
int ScreenMaxY;

short pattern[8]={~0xFF, ~0xFF, ~0xFF, ~0xFF, ~0xFF, ~0xFF, ~0xFF, ~0xFF};
HBRUSH brush=::CreatePatternBrush(::CreateBitmap(8, 8, 1, 1, pattern));

void bar(int nLeft, int nTop, int nRight, int nBottom)
{
    RECT rect;
    rect.left   = nLeft;
    rect.right  = nRight;
    rect.top    = nTop;
    rect.bottom = nBottom;

    ::SetTextColor(hDCMem, 0xFF00FF);
    ::SetBkColor(hDCMem, 0xFF00FF);
    //brush=::CreatePatternBrush(::CreateBitmap(8, 8, 1, 1, pattern));
    ::FillRect(hDCMem, &rect, brush);
}

void flush(){
    ::BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, ScreenMaxX, ScreenMaxY, hDCMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}

CRITICAL_SECTION graphics_cs;

uint8_t thread_cnt=0;
uint8_t total_threads=2;
HANDLE turnstile1=CreateSemaphoreW(nullptr, 0, 2, nullptr);

void thread_func(int num){
    int x,y;
    if(num==0){
        x=20; y=0;
    } else {
        x=110; y=0;
    }

    while(true) {
        while(true) {
            EnterCriticalSection(&graphics_cs);
            if (thread_cnt == num) {
                thread_cnt++;
                bar(x, y, x+40, y+40);
                y+=1;
                //flush();
                if(thread_cnt==total_threads){
                    thread_cnt = 0;
                    flush();
                    ReleaseSemaphore(turnstile1, total_threads, nullptr);
                }
                LeaveCriticalSection(&graphics_cs);
                break;
            } else {
                LeaveCriticalSection(&graphics_cs);
            }
        }

        WaitForSingleObject(turnstile1, INFINITE);

        Sleep(100);
    }
}

void mainx ()
{
    InitializeCriticalSection(&graphics_cs);
    for(int i=0; i<total_threads; i++){
        CreateThread (nullptr, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)thread_func, (LPVOID)i, 0, nullptr);
    }
}

DWORD Th(LPVOID param)
{
    (void)param;
    ::SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP,
                   10,
                   10,
                   400,
                   500,
                   SWP_SHOWWINDOW
    );
    mainx();
    flush();
    return 0;
}
DWORD g_nMainThreadID;

//processing main window messages
long FAR PASCAL WindowProc(HWND   hWnd,UINT   message, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:   flush();
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int PASCAL WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR  lpCmdLine,  int  nShowCmd )
{
    (void)hPrevInstance, (void)lpCmdLine;
    WNDCLASS  wc;
    MSG       msg;

    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = NULL;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = "Menu_one";
    wc.lpszClassName = "NAME";

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) {return 0; };


    //main window
    hwnd = CreateWindow("NAME",    
                        "!", 
                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        HWND_DESKTOP, 
                        NULL, 
                        hInstance,
                        NULL
    );
    ScreenMaxX = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    ScreenMaxY = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    hDC = ::GetDC(hwnd);
    hDCMem  = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    hbitmap = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, ScreenMaxX, ScreenMaxY );
    ::SelectObject(hDCMem, hbitmap);
    auto hbrush = (HBRUSH)::GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    ::SelectObject(hDCMem, hbrush);
    ::PatBlt(hDCMem, 0,0, ScreenMaxX, ScreenMaxY, PATCOPY );
    ::DeleteObject(hbrush);


    CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Th, (LPVOID)hwnd, 0,&g_nMainThreadID);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);


    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

In Windows 7 the stripes are drawn with the same speed as expected. But in Windows XP the speed is different:

[image: different speed]

If I uncomment either `//brush=::CreatePatternBrush(::CreateBitmap(8, 8, 1, 1, pattern));` or `//flush();` lines, the speed of drawing in Windows XP will be the same. Why does this fix the problem and why does the behaviour of the initital code differ in different versions of Windows?

**Update**

When I add `std::cout<<"num = "<<num<<" : bar call\n";` and `std::cout<<"num = "<<num<<" : flush call\n";` after `bar` and `flush` calls in `thread_func`, the output is

```
num = 0 : bar call
num = 1 : bar call
num = 1 : flush call
num = 0 : bar call
num = 1 : bar call
num = 1 : flush call
num = 0 : bar call
num = 1 : bar call
num = 1 : flush call
num = 0 : bar call
num = 1 : bar call
num = 1 : flush call
...
```

The order seems correct, but the left stripe is not drawn immediately after the flush call.

Comment: If threads don't get the same amount of processor love then one will fall behind.  Bummer if one always runs on a hyper-threaded core.  Measure actual elapsed time to figure out how much to draw, don't just assume 40.  GetTickCount() gets the job done.  Now neither scheduling nor core performance nor the actual amount of Sleep() nor what brushes you create matter anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant If one thread has more priority then it will wait for other on `turnstile1`. I've tried to print a message to console after the `flush` call and coordinate change and it seems correct, but the image on the screen does not reflect this. And I have run this program even on single core CPU.

Comment: Yes, you can remove that turnstile code as well, one less thing to debug.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I can't use your approach (and honestly I didn't get it) because the real code is far more complex and it is a kind of educational task.

Comment: I know, I can usually tell when I should not post the correct answer :)

Comment: Rendering changed a lot between XP and Windows 7.  In XP, your GDI operations changed the actual desktop image.  The compositing window manager in Windows 7 keeps each each application's image in texture memory and composites on the fly.  Depending on drivers and versions, your GDI operations might go directly to that texture memory, or it might go to an intermediate buffer and the DWM will need to periodically copy fresh images over to texture memory (or so I was told).  Also be aware that GDI batches operations which can cause bursty rendering on slower machines.

Comment: This blog post supports some of my claims:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/greg_schechter/2006/05/03/redirecting-gdi-directx-and-wpf-applications/

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy the behaviour seems to be incorrect in Windows XP, where there is no DWM. If you are interested I've narrowed down the problem. I've found that there is a strange buffering in `FillRect` function, I have either to call it 18 times in one thread or call some other GDI function after it (`BitBlt`,`CreatePatternBrush`) to make the rectangles appear in `hDCMem`. The first explains the different speed of drawing. In later versions of Windows there is no such buffering.

Comment: My point was a lot has changed in the rendering layers, so the difference in behavior might not be related to the use of threads.  Also, while GDI batches on both XP and 7, in practice that doesn't seem to be much of an issue anymore on 7.  Try calling GdiSetBatchLimit to set the limit to 1.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy thank you, I didn't know about GDI batching at all. With `GdiSetBatchLimit` the behavior is the same. Could you write an answer, so I can accept it? It is also a bit strange that not all GDI functions can be accumulated, for example, `Ellipse`, although it returns `BOOL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling bits from my comments into an answer.

Be aware that GDI batches operations which can cause bursty rendering on slower machines.  While GDI batches on both XP and 7, in practice that doesn't seem to be much of an issue anymore on 7. Try calling [GdiSetBatchLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144846(v=vs.85).aspx) to set the limit to 1.  This will cause GDI to flush after every call, which may be slower overall, but should eliminate the bursty behavior.